Postgres jsonb: How to get mongo like projections?
I have a jsonb column containing data like this:
{
    firstName: 'John',
    address: {
        street: 'bumpyroad',
        postalCode: '123',
    }
}
{
    firstName: 'Martin',
    address: {
        street: 'anotherroad',
        postalCode: '456',
    }
}

I want to select the street and preserve the json structure. The desired output is
{
    address: {
        street: 'bumpyroad'
    }
}
{
    address: {
        street: 'anotherroad'
    }
}

In Mongo the same can be done with {$projection:{"address.street":1}}. How can i achieve this with jsonb in postgres?
I tried
SELECT myjsonbcolumn->'address'->'street' FROM "sometable"
but this returns a flat list of strings and does not preserve the parent structure.

Offtopic and just my opinion: Your structure would be much better using a json array for all persons and their address.

You can build the desired structure with jsonb_build_object(), incorporating the value in it: demo
SELECT jsonb_pretty(
            jsonb_build_object( 
                 'address'
                 ,jsonb_build_object(
                       'street'
                       ,myjsonbcolumn#>'{address,street}')))
FROM "sometable";




jsonb_pretty




{    "address": {        "street": "bumpyroad"    }}


{    "address": {        "street": "anotherroad"    }}




jsonb_pretty returns text not jsonb, because jsonb has no formatting.

All formatting/pretty-printing functions yield a string type and all non-text-based types have no formatting in that sense, unless pretty-printed/formatted. Functions with format, pretty, astext, to_char have it in the name. I don't agree stuff that's right in the name of something needs to be repeated but I guess it won't hurt either. Thanks for a clarifying comment.
